# How can I go to another view controller without segues [ SWIFT 5]

Tags: ios, swift

I want to perform to another view controller from sign up, but when I do it, sidebar disappear. Any help?

```
@IBAction func signUpPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if let email = emailTextField.text, let parola = parolaTextField.text{
      
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: parola) { (authResult, eroare) in
                
                if let e = eroare {
                    print(e.localizedDescription)
                }
                else
                {
                    self.transitionToHome()
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    func transitionToHome() {
        
        let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController
        
        view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
    }
```

[ViewControllers] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6tsh.png

Comment: Is the most right view image homeViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because sidebar button is a part of navigation controller, and when you try to instantiate homeViewController, you initiate only controller, that actually has no navigationVC. RootViewController should be navigation controller. You need to remove identifier (Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) from HomeViewController in storyboard, and set it to navigation controller in which it embedded by.

```
func transitionToHome() {
    
    let homeNavController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? UINavigationController
    
    view.window?.rootViewController = homeNavController
    view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

transitionToHome() is create an instance of view controller by itself which is why the left side navigation navigation disappears.

If you want to be able to keep the navigation, then you have to create a `UINavigationController` with an embedded root view controller of `HomeViewController`

```
let homeNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)
view.window?.rootViewController = homeNavigationController
view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```